# CKEditor Compact HTML code

Tags: tabs, ckeditor, indentation, spaces

Is there anyway to tell CKEditor to not indent the code it generates from user input?
It would be great if it would just add no extra spaces or tabs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify settings like that in the htmlWriter class. Check out this page on the documentation:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting

Comment: Any idea how I can set that from PHP? It doesn't say and I couldn't figure it out.